# How to get the installed path from the registery?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to get the installed path from the registry. I have installed the python in my machine. I want to get the installed path from the registry in VC++ 6.0. I am trying the following code but it is returning error code (87) that means file not found:

```
dwRet = RegQueryValueEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                         TEXT("SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\${PYTHON_VERSION}\InstallPath"),
                         NULL,
                         NULL,
                         (LPBYTE)cbData,
                         NULL );
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Replace ${PYTHON_VERSION} by the **actual** version of python. There is no "${PYTHON_VERSION}" key in the registry, you can check this with regedit.

Comment: And replace "\" by "\\" in your string.

Comment: Did my answer helped you, or do you still fail to read the key?

Answer (score 1):

working code:

```
HKEY hKey;
if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                  TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Python\\PythonCore\\3.3\\InstallPath"),
                  0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
    TCHAR Path[ MAX_PATH ];
    DWORD Size = (DWORD)sizeof( Path);
    DWORD dwRet = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL,(LPBYTE)Path, &Size );
    RegCloseKey( hKey );
}
```

If you don't know the Python version, you should enumerate the subkeys of PythonCore. See [Enumerating Registry Subkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724256.aspx)